# Cannot interpolate environment variable in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple docker compose file to create a Mysql database for my app. But I cannot interpolate the environment variable `MYSQL_PORT` to set a custom port. Running `docker compose up` with the configuration below results in a random port being assigned to mysql.

The path to the env file does work, since I have env variables configuring the database.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - ../../.env
    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_PORT}:3306

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

.env

```
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_DATABASE=final_project_database
MYSQL_USER=db_user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=some_db_user_password
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `--env-file` option with `docker-compose up` command. env_file declared in your MySQL service applies only for container env

Comment: I tried that previously with `docker-compose --env-file ../../.env up`. If I do this I get an error telling me to specify either MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD or MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD. So I'm assuming it is not reading the .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Move your .env file to the same directory as the docker-compose file and change the `env_file` to point to it. That way both docker-compose and the container will use the same environment file.

Right now it's only the container that's using it.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_PORT}:3306

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```